# Visual Studio 2012 Coded UI Testing - Cannot perform 'Click' on the hidden control

Tags: visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to create Coded UI Tests for our application developped in C++ but I am having issues detecing a menuitem and I am having the following error:

[image] [image]

When I run the DrawHighlight,it doesn't detect anything, I have been looking in internet for various answers but didn't worked, I tried to put also "AlwaysSearch" but no success.

I added a screenshot of the menu, I am trying to access "Journal - Ventes",

here is the coded from UI.Map.Designer:

```
    public void RecordedMethod1()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WinMenuItem uIVentesMenuItem = this.UIIntelliXiCom2012GoldWindow.UIItemWindow.UIBarredesmenusClient.UIVentesMenuItem;
        WinMenu uIVentesMenu = this.UIIntelliXiCom2012GoldWindow.UIItemWindow.UIBarredesmenusClient.UIVentesMenu;
        WinMenuItem uIJournalventesMenuItem = this.UIIntelliXiCom2012GoldWindow.UIItemToolBar1.UIJournalventesMenuItem;
        #endregion

        // Click 'Ventes' menu item
        Mouse.Click(uIVentesMenuItem, new Point(20, 14));

        // Mouse hover 'Ventes' popup menu at (19, -8)
        Mouse.Hover(uIVentesMenu, new Point(19, -8));

        // Click 'Journal - ventes' menu item
        Mouse.Click(uIJournalventesMenuItem, new Point(45, 8));
    }
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: Your error message suggests that the target control is hidden.  Hidden controls can't be clicked by the user, and therefore can't be clicked by automation either.  What is it that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: As Dan says. Plus: There is no quick answer unless we see the application and the test code, even then an answer may take careful analysis to find. There are some good guides on the MSDN web site for sorting this out so I suggest doing some more web searching. Often you get clues from the stack trace but just showing a screenshot where the interesting bits of stack trace are not shown (the right hand side is missing) does not help.

Comment: Actually no it is not a hidden control, it is a MenuItem (I added a screenshot of the menu and the generated coded). It is a BCG Control, can this be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same Problem.

Its a [BUG](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/09/17/coded-ui-mtm-issues-on-internet-explorer-with-kb2870699.aspx)!

[Update 4 RC 4 for VS12](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40338) fixed this for me! (VS2012.4 RC.exe is what you are looking for).

Comment: We faced same error. But condition is different. 1.We run test case by MTM; 2.We build test case by VSTS 2012 Update 4; 3. TFS is 2012 RTM; 4.BDT environment test agent is 2012 RTM; Solution is to update test agent to 2012 Update 4.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you did the setup (Tools > Options> Enviornment > Tabs and Windows> Check the checkbox under 'Tools Windows') part ,its not working. In some cases of hidden controls, even 'Mouse.Hover()' isn't working.It is happening when you are trying with silverlight controls.This is a kind of BUG.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know if you are able to access the control properties while dragging it to the control. If yes, then please post the control property with complete object hierarchy.

Also, I see there is a Mouse hover event recoreded -

```
    // Mouse hover 'Ventes' popup menu at (19, -8)
    Mouse.Hover(uIVentesMenu, new Point(19, -8))
```

Can you tell me if it is important to do a mouse hover before doing a Mouse click on 'Journal - ventes'?

Comment: This is not an answer but I believe it to be a useful contribution to the question, to seek more data. The author does not have enough status to be able to add comments to the original question.

Comment: Still waiting for a response.

Comment: You may get a better response if you add a comment to the question so its author gets notified (read the **help** link below the **Add comment** button). Viewing the questioner's profile suggests they have not visited for two days - but it is the weekend now.

Comment: I am not able to drag to the control as it is a menu item, the menu closes and I cannot get to the menu item. On the other hand, the hover was just a test, it has no influence on the click.

Answer (score 0):

when you are not able to click on hidden control as  it is a menu item,in visual studio 2012 go to Tools Menu --> options -->  Environment --> Tabs and Windows -->in Tool Windows Tab,Check "Show auto-hidden windows on mouse over"option.
then it will be able to detect hidden control.